# Java FileReader Крякозябры

Tags: java

```
package test001;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test_001 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fileLocation1 = bufReader.readLine();
        String fileLocation2 = bufReader.readLine();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation1);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation2);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            int data = scanner.nextInt();
            list.add(data);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            writer.write(list.get(i));
        }
        bufReader.close();
        scanner.close();
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

> Суть в том, что числа из первого файла копируются во второй. Но
>   проблема в том, что во втором текстовом файле, в который должно все
>   скопироваться, появляются "крякозябры"(прямоугольники). Думал проблема
>   в коде, но я создал массив, в который эти числа копировались и
>   оказалось, что числа действительно проходили через цикл while. В чем
>   может быть проблема?

Comment: может в кодировке проблема?

Comment: Да нет, стоит utf-8

Comment: Может нужно не int считывать? Через 20 мин проверю, отпишусь

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что вы пишете не так, как читаете. Читаете вы разделенные пробелом или пустой строкой строковые данные, представляющие собой числа. Напр. `"1 2 3"` - это три числа.

```
    while(scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        int data = scanner.nextInt(); // строка "100500" преобразуется в число 100500
        //  вызовом Integer.parseInt( String str )
        list.add(data); // int 100500 пакуется (autoboxing) в объект Integer
        //  вызовом Integer.valueOf( int value )
    }
```

Для записи вы вызываете перегруженный метод `FileWriter.write`, и он делает не то, что вы от него ждете.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        // list.get(i) - объект Integer
        // у writer.write три перегруженных (overload) версии с одним аргументом
        //   write( String str )   - Integer - не String 
        //   write( char[] cbuf )  - и не char[]
        //   write( int c )        - но он распаковывается в int (Integer.intValue)
        writer.write(list.get(i)); 
    }
```

Метод [`write( int c )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write%28int%29), определенный в `OutputStreamWriter` превращает `int` в `char` (отбрасыванием старших двух байтов), и записывает получившийся символ в какой-то кодировке. В итоге вряд ли получаются символы арабских цифр.

Вам нужно, во-первых, снова превращать числа в строки (`writer.write( list.get(i).toString() );` или `Integer.toString`), во-вторых дописывать отдельным вызовом разделитель (`writer.write( ' ' );` - пробел или `writer.write( "\r\n" );` - перевод строки в Windows).

Вообще именно для копирования файлов, без учета содержимого, нужно использовать не `Reader`ы и `Writer`ы (семейство классов, работающих с символьными потоками), а `InputStream`ы и `OutputStream`ы, которые работают просто с байтами.

Comment: Просто делаю задание на сайте